# How to search a webpage with keywords from a .txt list?

Tags: c#, java

I am trying to find a tutorial or help on how to import a .txt list of keywords to put into a search function:

```
http://www.website.com/search.php?word=WORDHERE
```

it would be a url of that sort, but I want it to go through each item in the list and replace wordhere with that word so it searches each word in the list.

If it comes up as "No matches found." it will create a new list with all the non-matches. I don't care if it exports it to a new .txt or if it floods into another text box. either works.

If a search is matched it will simply ignore it and move to the next.

I'm a newb :( send me to some help :P

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You will solve this problem more effectively by taking some time to learn how to use this site. Here's some help: http://stackoverflow.com/about Be sure to review "Get answers to practical, detailed questions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the .txt file contains one word per line, here is a simple solution:

```cs
string[] keywords = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\keywords.txt");

List<string> nomatch = new List<string>();

System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

foreach (string word in keywords)
{
    string response = wc.DownloadString("http://www.website.com/search.php?word=" + word);

    if (response != null && response.Contains("No matches found"))
        nomatch.Add(word);
}

if (nomatch.Count > 0)
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\nomatch.txt", nomatch.ToArray());
```

Comment: Oh goodness this helps me beyond words. Thank you so much!